"Program 'xxx' was overridden with the compiled executable 'xxx' and therefore cannot be used during configuration" error
Using Meson build system, I tried to run flatc  program which is got from find_program('flatc'). But Meson complains as "ERROR: Program 'flatc' was overridden with the compiled executable 'flatc' and therefore cannot be used during configuration".
meson.build
dependency('flatbuffers')
flatc = find_program('flatc')
run_command(flatc, '--version', check: true) # error

flatbuffers.wrap (Copied from WrabDB)
[wrap-file]
directory = flatbuffers-24.3.6
source_url = https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/archive/v24.3.6.tar.gz
source_filename = flatbuffers-24.3.6.tar.gz
source_hash = 5d8bfbf5b1b4c47f516e7673677f0e8db0efd32f262f7a14c3fd5ff67e2bd8fc
patch_filename = flatbuffers_24.3.6-1_patch.zip
patch_url = https://wrapdb.mesonbuild.com/v2/flatbuffers_24.3.6-1/get_patch
patch_hash = bc0e1035a67ae74b1f862491fe2b0fd49b2889d989508143fff0a45508421bd7
source_fallback_url = https://github.com/mesonbuild/wrapdb/releases/download/flatbuffers_24.3.6-1/flatbuffers-24.3.6.tar.gz
wrapdb_version = 24.3.6-1

[provide]
flatbuffers = flatbuffers_dep
program_names = flatc, flathash


meson v1.3.2

fedora 39


Meson documentation about run_command explains that "The first argument can be either a string or an executable you have detected earlier with find_program.", which makes me believe that I'm using the command in the right way.
How can I execute flatc program so that I can compile flatbuffers schemas in the configuration stage?

Separate Meson documentation states that find_program() will only search places inside the project in two seperate places.
Once at the top -
"program_name here is a string that can be an executable or script to be searched for in PATH or other places inside the project."
and once in the list with 7 options in option 5.
"5. Project's source tree relative to the current subdir

If you use the return value of configure_file(), the current subdir inside the build tree is used instead."

The documentation I've read seems to be heavily implying that it will only work with other projects that are currently inside the same package as the project executing this function, or with programs that are subclasses of the class you're executing it in.
//This paragraph is primarily speculation of possibilities for this error if you're certain that you're using it for a subclass of this program as the documentation specified, feel free to ignore it entirely if you wish.
If you are using this command to look for a program that is within the build tree and is a subclass of the class you're running it from, then I can't provide a concrete answer on why it's occurring, but I do suspect primarily that it's something to do with method overriding/overloading, and secondarily that it might have to do with super() implementation, and what appears to be least likely is that a field or class was made public instead of private. It might be helpful to double-check these things though, just in case.
//Speculation stops here.
However, in the event that you were using this command in a way that the program you're searching for is not in the build tree or a subclass of this program, then that would be the problem. If it's not the problem, then I can't provide a concrete answer, but please read the speculative paragraph for a list of potential problems that you might want to double-check for.
